# Need UI/UX Design layout name

Tags: user-interface, user-experience

I am an UI newbie. Can any one please tell what is the "layout" name or what is the layout design called in which the travel portal **Cleartrip.com** is designed. It has got a "left hand side option" like Flights, Hotel etc in vertical fashion and "right hand side selection" with their accompanied parameters. I know it is minimalist design but is there any specific sort of "name" which is called for this sort for design? I will be very obliged to get answers from experts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would describe it as a 3 column fixed width layout with menu navigation on the left column, body/content in the middle and and informational banners on the right column.